# How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

How do I connect to a MySQL database using a python program?

Comment: Most answers here focus on installing MySQLdb library, I would really suggest opting for MySQL Connector/Python provided by MySQL/Oracle, which makes the process much simpler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python/20959654#20959654

Comment: The problem with using Oracle's Connector/Python is that it has subtle bugs and other integration issues. It's easy to install, but nearly impossible to get to work for all the real-world use cases I've tried it for. Hence why I always recommend MySQLdb.

Comment: @Mr.Napik I'm using `pymysql` because it's pure free Python according to [this comparison](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/PyMySQL_evaluation).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_create_db.asp   : I know that senior devs looks down upon w3school tutorials but they are a good started. Go though it !

Answer (score 1305):

### Connecting to MYSQL with Python 2 in three steps

**1 - Setting**

You must install a MySQL driver before doing anything. Unlike PHP, Only the SQLite driver is installed by default with Python. The most used package to do so is [MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) but it's hard to install it using easy_install. Please note MySQLdb only supports Python 2.

For Windows user, you can get an [exe of MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=22307).

For Linux, this is a casual package (python-mysqldb). (You can use `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb` (for debian based distros), `yum install MySQL-python` (for rpm-based), or `dnf install python-mysql` (for modern fedora distro) in command line to download.)

For Mac, you can [install MySQLdb using Macport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x#1448476).

**2 - Usage**

After installing, Reboot. This is not mandatory, But it will prevent me from answering 3 or 4 other questions in this post if something goes wrong. So please reboot.

Then it is just like using any other package :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="john",         # your username
                     passwd="megajonhy",  # your password
                     db="jonhydb")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]

db.close()
```

Of course, there are thousand of possibilities and options; this is a very basic example. You will have to look at the documentation. [A good starting point](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/).

**3 - More advanced usage**

Once you know how it works, You may want to use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping) to avoid writing SQL manually and manipulate your tables as they were Python objects. The most famous ORM in the Python community is [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

I strongly advise you to use it: your life is going to be much easier.

I recently discovered another jewel in the Python world: [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). It's a very lite ORM, really easy and fast to setup then use. It makes my day for small projects or stand alone apps, Where using big tools like SQLAlchemy or Django is overkill :

```py
import peewee
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('jonhydb', user='john', passwd='megajonhy')

class Book(peewee.Model):
    author = peewee.CharField()
    title = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

Book.create_table()
book = Book(author="me", title='Peewee is cool')
book.save()
for book in Book.filter(author="me"):
    print book.title
```

This example works out of the box. Nothing other than having peewee (`pip install peewee`) is required.

Comment: Glad you like peewee!!  I've added support for MySQL as well as some [documentation](http://charlesleifer.com/docs/peewee/peewee/uses.html#using-with-mysql) on integrating with it.  Happy hacking!

Comment: Note, as of writing this, MySQLdb does not support Python 3. The sourceforge page says "Python 3 support coming soon" but it has not been updated since 2012-10-08. For Python 3 there's [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) and [oursql](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/index.html).

Answer (score 202):

Here's one way to do it, using [MySQLdb](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/), which only supports Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

# Connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="appuser",
                     passwd="",
                     db="onco")

cursor = db.cursor()

# Execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM location")

# Commit your changes if writing
# In this case, we are only reading data
# db.commit()

# Get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = cursor.rowcount

# Get and display one row at a time
for x in range(0, numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[0], "-->", row[1]

# Close the connection
db.close()
```

[Reference here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/lim/connecting-to-mysql-from-python-4529)

Answer (score 145):

If you do not need MySQLdb, but would accept any library, I would very, very much recommend MySQL Connector/Python from MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/.

It is one package (around 110k), pure Python, so it is system independent, and dead simple to install. You just download, double-click, confirm license agreement and go. There is no need for Xcode, MacPorts, compiling, restarting …

Then you connect like:

```
import mysql.connector    
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')

try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""
      select 3 from your_table
   """)
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   print result
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: `pip install mysql-connector-python` will also work. I don't see where it says no longer supported on PyPi? Great if you don't have access to the gcc/C compilers on your system, and therefore can't install `mysqldb`.

Answer (score 131):

Oracle (MySQL) now supports a pure Python connector.  That means no binaries to install: it's just a Python library.  It's called "Connector/Python".

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

After installations, you can see some usage examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Comment: is this faster than using mysqldb?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also, it's less hassle than MySQLdb and the API is better in my opinion. This should be the answer.

Comment: using the official mysql connector of python is the best way to win time

Comment: Agree that Connector/Python works well, was easier to set up than MySQLdb, and has great documentation, as Karthic referenced above. And it supports Python 3, which MySQLdb does not (yet).

Comment: You need to _register_ for this? :/

Comment: @J0hnG4lt You can just click on "No thanks, just start my download" below the login form (which actually seems mandatory, but isn't).

Answer (score 128):

> Stop Using MySQLDb if you want to avoid installing mysql headers just to access mysql from python.

Use [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL). It does all of what MySQLDb does, but it was implemented purely in Python with ***NO External Dependencies***.  This makes the installation process on all operating systems consistent and easy.  `pymysql` is a drop in replacement for MySQLDb and IMHO there is no reason to ever use MySQLDb for anything... EVER! - *`PTSD from installing MySQLDb on Mac OSX and *Nix systems`*, but that's just me.

**Installation**

`pip install pymysql`

> That's it... you are ready to play.

**Example usage from pymysql Github repo**

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

> **ALSO - Replace MySQLdb in existing code quickly and transparently**

If you have existing code that uses MySQLdb, you can easily replace it with pymysql using this simple process:

```
# import MySQLdb << Remove this line and replace with:
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

All subsequent references to MySQLdb will use pymysql transparently.

Answer (score 26):

Try using [MySQLdb](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/). MySQLdb only supports Python 2.

There is a how to page here: http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html

---

From the page:

```
# server_version.py - retrieve and display database server version

import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "testuser",
                        passwd = "testpass",
                        db = "test")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
row = cursor.fetchone ()
print "server version:", row[0]
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()
```

Answer (score 25):

Run this command in your terminal to install mysql connector:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

And run this in your python editor to connect to MySQL:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="username",
      passwd="password",
      database="database_name"
)
```

Samples to execute MySQL Commands (in your python edior):

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))")    
mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('John', 'Highway 21')")    
mydb.commit() # Use this command after insert, update, delete commands
```

For more commands: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

Comment: Can you please answer this?? It is related to `mysql-connector` only.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59405740/my-program-is-not-being-able-to-store-values-in-mysql-using-mysql-connector-lib

Comment: Some guys already answered your question there. You just forgot to run `mydb.commit()` after inserting values into table

Answer (score 18):

### For newer versions of Python (>=3.6)

Use either [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) or [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) (*recommended*).

### For older versions of Python (<3.7, 2.4 <= Python <= 2.7)

If you are working on an older version of Python (*unfortunately*), then you could also try out -> [oursql](https://pypi.org/project/oursql/).

**Please note however, that the project is no longer maintained, and bug fixes are not being pushed either.**

---

As a db driver, there is also [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/index.html). Some of the reasons listed on that link, which say why oursql is better:

> - oursql has real parameterization, sending the SQL and data to MySQL completely separately.

- oursql allows text or binary data to be streamed into the database and streamed out of the database, instead of requiring everything to be buffered in the client.
- oursql can both insert rows lazily and fetch rows lazily.
- oursql has unicode support on by default.
- oursql supports python 2.4 through 2.7 without any deprecation warnings on 2.6+ (see PEP 218) and without completely failing on 2.7 (see PEP 328).
- oursql runs natively on python 3.x.

#### So how to connect to mysql with oursql?

Very similar to mysqldb:

```
import oursql

db_connection = oursql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='foo',passwd='foobar',db='db_name')
cur=db_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `tbl_name`")
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]
```

The [tutorial in the documentation](http://packages.python.org/oursql/index.html) is pretty decent.

And of course for ORM SQLAlchemy is a good choice, as already mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: The project is no longer being maintained; the last commits to the repository were in 2016. It won’t work with Python 3.7 or newer and so is no longer useable on any currently supported Python release.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for bringing this to my notice. I have updated the answer to reflect the more up to date libraries.

Answer (score 15):

## SqlAlchemy

---

> SQLAlchemy is the Python SQL toolkit and Object Relational Mapper that
>   gives application developers the full power and flexibility of SQL.
>   SQLAlchemy provides a full suite of well known enterprise-level
>   persistence patterns, designed for efficient and high-performing
>   database access, adapted into a simple and Pythonic domain language.

### Installation

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

### RAW query

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine = create_engine("mysql://<user_name>:<password>@<host_name>/<db_name>")
session_obj = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(session_obj)

# insert into database
session.execute("insert into person values(2, 'random_name')")
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

### ORM way

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("mysql://<user_name>:<password>@<host_name>/<db_name>")
session_obj = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(session_obj)

# Bind the engine to the metadata of the Base class so that the
# declaratives can be accessed through a DBSession instance
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    # Here we define columns for the table person
    # Notice that each column is also a normal Python instance attribute.
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

# insert into database
person_obj = Person(id=12, name="name")
session.add(person_obj)
session.flush()
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 14):

Best way to connect to MySQL from python is to Use MySQL Connector/Python because it is official Oracle driver for MySQL for working with Python and it works with both Python 3 and Python 2.

follow the steps mentioned below to connect MySQL

1. install connector using pip

   `pip install mysql-connector-python`

or you can download the installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

2. Use `connect()` method of mysql connector python to connect to MySQL.pass the required argument to `connect()` method. i.e. Host, username, password, and database name.
3. Create `cursor` object from connection object returned by `connect()`method to execute SQL queries.
4. close the connection after your work completes.

**Example**:

```
import mysql.connector
 from mysql.connector import Error
 try:
     conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='hostname',
                         database='db',
                         user='root',
                         password='passcode')
     if conn.is_connected():
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute("select database();")
       record = cursor.fetchall()
       print ("You're connected to - ", record)
 except Error as e :
    print ("Print your error msg", e)
 finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(conn.is_connected()):
       cursor.close()
       conn.close()
```

Reference  - https://pynative.com/python-mysql-database-connection/

**Important API of MySQL Connector Python**

- For DML operations - Use `cursor.execute()` and `cursor.executemany()` to run query. and after this use `connection.commit()` to persist your changes to DB
- To fetch data      - Use `cursor.execute()` to run query and `cursor.fetchall()`, `cursor.fetchone()`, `cursor.fetchmany(SIZE)` to fetch data

Answer (score 11):

Despite all answers above, in case you do not want to connect to a specific database upfront, for example, if you want to create the database still (!), you can use `connection.select_db(database)`, as demonstrated in the following.

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='mahdi',
                         password='mahdi',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+database)
connection.select_db(database)
sql_create = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+tablename+(timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)"
cursor.execute(sql_create)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 10):

Even though some of you may mark this as a duplicate and get upset that I am copying someone else's answer, I would *REALLY* like to highlight an aspect of Mr. Napik's response.   Because I missed this, I caused nationwide website downtime (9min).  If only someone shared this information, I could have prevented it!

Here is his code:

```
import mysql.connector    
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("""select 3 from your_table""")
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   print(result)
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

The important thing here is the **Try** and **Finally** clause.  This allows connections to *ALWAYS* be closed, regardless of what happens in the cursor/sqlstatement portion of the code.  A lot of active connections cause DBLoadNoCPU to spike and could crash a db server.

I hope this warning helps to save servers and ultimately jobs! :D

Answer (score 7):

[MySQLdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) is the straightforward way. You get to execute SQL queries over a connection. Period.

My preferred way, which is also pythonic, is to use the mighty [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead. Here is a [query related](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html) tutorial, and here is a tutorial on [ORM capabilities](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html) of SQLALchemy.

Comment: The links are dead, can you look into that and update it with the correct link ?

Comment: Sorry, your last two links are still dead as at June 2020.

Answer (score 7):

for Python3.6 I found two driver: pymysql and mysqlclient. I tested the performance between them and got the result: the mysqlclient is faster.

below is my test process(need install python lib profilehooks to analyze time elapse：

raw sql: `select * from FOO;`

immediatly execute in mysql terminal:
`46410 rows in set (0.10 sec)`

pymysql (2.4s):

```
from profilehooks import profile
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', db='foo')
c = connection.cursor()

@profile(immediate=True)
def read_by_pymysql():
    c.execute("select * from FOO;")
    res = c.fetchall()

read_by_pymysql()
```

here's the pymysql profile:
[image]

mysqlclient (0.4s)

```
from profilehooks import profile
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', db='foo')
c = connection.cursor()

@profile(immediate=True)
def read_by_mysqlclient():
    c.execute("select * from FOO;")
    res = c.fetchall()

read_by_mysqlclient()
```

here's the mysqlclient profile:
[image]

So, it seems that mysqlclient is much faster than pymysql

Answer (score 5):

Just a modification in above answer. 
Simply run this command to install mysql for python

```
sudo yum install MySQL-python
sudo apt-get install MySQL-python
```

remember! It is case sensitive.

Comment: I installed MySQL-python via yum install. The installation was complete but I cannot import the MySQLdb module. It says no such module. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: It's not clear which answer you mean when you say "above answer". Please make your answer complete in itself. If you want to refer to other answers, please link to the specific answer.

Answer (score 4):

mysqlclient is the best as others only provide support to specific versions of python

```
 pip install mysqlclient
```

example code

```
    import mysql.connector
    import _mysql
    db=_mysql.connect("127.0.0.1","root","umer","sys")
    #db=_mysql.connect(host,user,password,db)
    # Example of how to insert new values:
    db.query("""INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('01', 'myname')""")
    db.store_result()
    db.query("SELECT * FROM new1.table1 ;") 
    #new1 is scheme table1 is table mysql 
    res= db.store_result()
    for i in range(res.num_rows()):
        print(result.fetch_row())
```

see https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Comment: +1 for proposing the fastest solution for python 3. However, `mysql.connector` and `_mysql` give both an import error (though the second option should work according to the documentation). `import MySQLdb` works, and then `MySQLdb.connect...`

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at [Storm](https://storm.canonical.com). It is a simple SQL mapping tool which allows you to easily edit and create SQL entries without writing the queries.

Here is a simple example:

```
from storm.locals import *

# User will be the mapped object; you have to create the table before mapping it
class User(object):
        __storm_table__ = "user" # table name
        ID = Int(primary=True) #field ID
        name= Unicode() # field name

database = create_database("mysql://root:password@localhost:3306/databaseName")
store = Store(database)

user = User()
user.name = u"Mark"

print str(user.ID) # None

store.add(user)  
store.flush() # ID is AUTO_INCREMENT

print str(user.ID) # 1 (ID)

store.commit() # commit all changes to the database
```

To find and object use:

```
michael = store.find(User, User.name == u"Michael").one()
print str(user.ID) # 10
```

Find with primary key:

```
print store.get(User, 1).name #Mark
```

For further information see the [tutorial](https://storm.canonical.com/Tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

This is Mysql DB connection

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'MyDB'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        details = request.form
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute ("_Your query_")
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

`PyMySQL 0.10.1` - Released: Sep 10, 2020, has support for python3 as well.

```sh
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

Simple code:

```py
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',passwd='root',db='fax')

# Create a Cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute the query
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fax.student")

# Read and print records
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

output:

```sh
(1, 'Petar', 'Petrovic', 1813, 'Njegusi')
(2, 'Donald', 'Tramp', 1946, 'New York')
(3, 'Bill', 'Gates', 1955, 'Seattle')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can connect your python code to mysql in this way.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                 user="appuser",
                 passwd="",
                 db="onco")

cursor = db.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

First step to get The Library:
Open terminal and execute `pip install mysql-python-connector`.
After the installation go the second step.

Second Step to import the library:
Open your python file and write the following code:
`import mysql.connector`

Third step to connect to the server:
Write the following code:

> conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=`you host name like  localhost or 127.0.0.1`,
> username=`your  username like root`,
> password = `your  password`)

Third step Making the cursor:
Making a cursor makes it easy for us to run queries.
To make the cursor use the following code:
`cursor = conn.cursor()`

Executing queries:
For executing queries you can do the following:
`cursor.execute(query)`

If the query changes any thing in the table you need to add the following code after the execution of the query:
`conn.commit()`

Getting values from a query:
If you want to get values from a query then you can do the following:
`cursor.excecute('SELECT * FROM` table_name`') for i in cursor: print(i) #Or for i in cursor.fetchall(): print(i)`

The fetchall() method returns a list with many tuples that contain the values that you requested ,row after row .

Closing the connection:
To close the connection you should use the following code:
`conn.close()`

Handling exception:
To Handel exception you can do it Vai the following method:
`try: #Logic pass except mysql.connector.errors.Error: #Logic  pass`
To use a database:
For example you are a account creating system where you are storing the data in a database named blabla, you can just add a database parameter to the connect() method ,like

`mysql.connector.connect(database =` database name`)`

don't remove other informations like host,username,password.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not come with an inbuilt Library to interact with MySQL, so in order to make a connection between the MySQL database and Python we need to install the MySQL driver or module for our Python Environment.

```bash
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

the mysql-connecter-python is an open source Python library that can connect your python code to the MySQL data base in a few lines of code. And it is very compatible with the latest version of Python.

After install the mysql-connector-python, you can connect to your MySQL database using the the following code snippet.

```py
import mysql.connector

Hostname = "localhost"
Username = "root"
Password ="admin"   #enter your MySQL password
 
#set connection
set_db_conn = mysql.connector.connect(host= Hostname, user=Username, password=Password)

if set_db_conn:
    print("The Connection between has been set and the Connection ID is:")
    #show connection id
    print(set_db_conn.connection_id)
```

**Connect Django with MySQL**

In Django, to connect your model or project to the MySQL data base, you need to install the mysqlclient library.

```bash
pip install mysqlclient
```

And to configure your Django setting so your project can connect to the MySQL database, you can use the following setting.

```py
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'database_name',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'databasepassword@123',
            'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
            'PORT': '3306',
            }
```

I have written a dedicated Python tutorial on my blog that covers how you can connect to a MySQL database and create tables using Python. To know more about it, [click here](https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/blog/how-to-use-mysql-database-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.3

CyMySQL
https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL

I have pip installed on my windows 7, just 
pip install cymysql

(you don't need cython)
quick and painless

Comment: You could create a new question on SO and comment with a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

first install the driver

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Then a basic code goes like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",      # db server, can be a remote one 
                     db="mydb"                  # database
                     user="mydb",               # username
                     passwd="mydb123",          # password for this username
                     )        

    # Create a Cursor object
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Create a query string. It can contain variables
    query_string = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE"

    # Execute the query
    cur.execute(query_string)

    # Get all the rows present the database
    for each_row in cur.fetchall():
        print each_row

    # Close the connection
    db.close()
except Exception, e:
    print 'Error ', e
```

Answer (score 0):

**First install the driver (Ubuntu)**

- sudo apt-get install python-pip
- sudo pip install -U pip
- sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
- sudo apt-get install MySQL-python

**MySQL database connection codes**

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root",passwd = "pass",db = "dbname")
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
row = cursor.fetchone ()
print "server version:", row[0]
cursor.close ()
conn.close ()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql clients in python like PyMySQL.

Answer (score -4):

First, install python-mysql connector from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

on Python console enter:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
import mysql.connector
```

Comment: The question was a little too broad, but this answer seems to be a bit too narrow (at least in the sense that installing and importing a module alone won't do). There also seems to be shell and python intermixed in single code block without any explanation or hints wrt what goes where and does what.