# Connecting to MySQL with Python 2.6...how?

Tags: python, mysql

All my searches, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-python) on Stack, point me to MySQLdb.  Unfortunately MySQLdb doesn't have a version for Python 2.6.

What am I to do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried compiling it for Python 2.6?  The APIs change very little in minor releases, so it's likely to Just Work (TM).

Edit:  According to [this post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-November/516315.html), it does work and the poster mentions that Windows binaries have been posted.

Comment: Yep...I found that a few things that were built for 2.5 "just work" with 2.6.