# How to Connect Python to MySQL DataBase ...?

Tags: python, mysql, database

A question about connecting Python To MySQL DB:

How Can I Do That ?!

Link, If You Have References or ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                       user="myusername",
                       passwd="mypassword",
                       db="mydb")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = %s;", (1,))
c.fetchone()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Note that MySQLdb uses `%s` as the parameter placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

## Why not google it?

The connect() method works nearly the same as with _mysql:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
```

To perform a query, you first need a cursor, and then you can execute queries on it:

```
c=db.cursor()
max_price=5
c.execute("""SELECT spam, eggs, sausage FROM breakfast
          WHERE price < %s""", (max_price,))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want higher level functionality, take a look at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/. It's an awesome piece of work.