# Python DB Connection Error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying example listed in [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-python)

When I try to execute the program in Python 3.0 GUI I receive error for last print statement

```
for x in range(0,numrows):
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0], "-->", row[1]
```

Error is Invalid Syntax for row[0]

Any Pointers would be helpful.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in python3 print is a function, so it's `print(row[0]+"-->"+row[1])`

Comment: But you can also do `print(row[0], "-->", row[1])` rather than the string concatenation.