# Connect to MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database set up in MySql Workbench and I want to connect and query the database from my python script.
I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Connector/Python (written by Geert). It is a pure Python implementation of the MySQL protocol, which means that it installs wherever Python installs.

You can find instructions on how to install it here: http://geert.vanderkelen.org/post/164/

Answer (score 2):

You want [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

But do yourself a favour and look into one of the excellent Python wrappers/ORMs: [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), [SQLObject](http://sqlobject.org/), or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

Comment: hi daniel, I installed MySQLdb but it turns out that it is not that quite simple to get it loaded in mac machine..:( I am getting this error... 'code'ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mohitdeepsingh/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/mohitdeepsingh/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture 'code' @DanielRoseman

Comment: Daniel's answer is the correct and standard answer. You are having some Apple specific issue. It is outside of the context of the original question (thus unlikely to be noticed by people who have a clue about it). You should figure out how to install software / Python modules on OS X. You could possibly make a separate question about that on some other StackExchange site after you have searched without finding a solution. Mats's other answer may help but eventually you are going to face the same Apple problem again with some other software.