# PYODBC to Pandas - DataFrame not working - Shape of passed values is (x,y), indices imply (w,z)

Tags: python, windows-8, pandas, 64-bit, pyodbc

I used pyodbc with python before but now I have installed it on a new machine ( win 8 64 bit, Python 2.7 64 bit, PythonXY with Spyder).

Before I used to (at the bottom you can find more real examples):

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
temp = cursor.fetchall()
data = pandas.DataFrame(temp,columns=columns)
```

and it would work fine. Now it seems like DataFrame is not able to convert from the data fetched from the cursor anymore. It returns:

Shape of passed values is (x,y), indices imply (w,z)

I kind of see where the issue is. Basically, imagine I fetch only one row. Then DataFrame would like to shape it (1,1), one element only. While I would like to have (1,X) where X is the length of the list.

I am not sure why the behavior changed. Maybe it is the Pandas version I have, or the pyodbc, but updating is problematic. I tried to update some modules but it screws up everything, any method I use (binaries--for the right machine/installation--pip install, easy-install,anything! etc.. which is very frustrating indeed. I would probably avoid Win 8 64 bit from now on for Python).

Real examples:

```
sql = 'Select * form TABLE'
cursor.execute(sql)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
data    = cursor.fetchall()
        con.close()
            results = DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Returns:
*** ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1540), indices imply (51, 1540)

Notice that:

```
ipdb> type(data)
<type 'list'>
ipdb> np.shape(data)
(1540, 51)
ipdb> type(data[0])
<type 'pyodbc.Row'>
```

Now, for example, if we do:

```
ipdb> DataFrame([1,2,3],columns=['a','b','c'])
```

*** ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 3), indices imply (3, 3)

and if we do:

```
ipdb> DataFrame([[1,2,3]],columns=['a','b','c'])
```

a  b  c
0  1  2  3

However, even trying:

```
ipdb> DataFrame([data[0]], columns=columns)
*** ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (51, 1)
```

or

```
ipdb> DataFrame(data[0], columns=columns)
*** PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Please help :) Thanks!

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: what is `temp` used for, where `data` comes from ?

Comment: Adding sample data will improve the likelihood of an answer.

Comment: Of course, the question is how do I get rid of the error and get DataFrame(data,columns=columns) to work. I said above: I would like to have (1,X) where X is the length of the list.

Comment: why do you need to specify the column names? pandas will detect them automatically. `pandas.read_sql(query_string, cnxn_obj)`

Comment: That method returns the same error to me (see the comment on your post below).

Answer (score 39):

As of Pandas 0.12 (I believe) you can do:

```
import pandas
import pyodbc

sql = 'select * from table'
cnn = pyodbc.connect(...)

data = pandas.read_sql(sql, cnn)
```

Prior to 0.12, you could do:

```
import pandas
from pandas.io.sql import read_frame
import pyodbc

sql = 'select * from table'
cnn = pyodbc.connect(...)

data = read_frame(sql, cnn)
```

Comment: It gives a similar error! In fact, as I mentioned, my code worked before as well. Therefore, it must be pyodbc that changed something?
  File "xxx.py", line 253, in xxx
    results    = read_frame(sql,con);

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 162, in read_frame
    coerce_float=coerce_float)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1115, in from_records
    columns)

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5338, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1825, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    construction_error(len(arrays),arrays[0].shape[1:],axes)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1799, in construction_error
    tuple(map(int, [len(ax) for ax in axes]))))

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (51,), indices imply (51, 1402)

Comment: To be clear, this happens on ALL of my machines, 2 desktop and 1 laptop. It didn't happen before (I updated all of them :/)

Comment: @user1350191 I can't reproduce this with pyodbc 3.0.6. Can you edit your question to show me *exactly* what you're doing when you try my method? (leave out your DB password, etc, obviously).

Comment: It's pretty basic and similar to what you wrote. I will see what I can do as soon as I get some 10 free minutes. In the meantime, consider that I am using pyodbc 3.0.7 with Python 2.7 (both 32 and 64 bit gives the same problem, both pythonxy and anaconda distribution as well).

Comment: This answer made my day.

Answer (score 17):

This is because the cursor returns not a list of tuples but a list of the Row objects, which are similar to tuples, better, actually, but they confuse the pandas dataframe constructor. In the original example, do this before creating the data frame:

```
for i in range(0,len(temp)):
    temp[i]=tuple(temp[i])
```

Comment: Gena, you're a freaking genius.  Took me hours trying every other solution on SO, and yours worked.

Comment: `df = pandas.DataFrame([tuple(t) for t in cursor.fetchall()])`

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. @MortenB has a beautiful solution.

Comment: ```temp = map(tuple, temp)``` is better