# Python - How to loop a ResultSet

Tags: python, oracle, loops, resultset, jaydebeapi

I'm working with Python and JayDeBeApi to connect to a Oracle-type database.

In the SELECT's statements I need to get about 10+ thousand of records.

In the first time I done by using the "fetchAll()" method, but this loads my memory and I wouldn't like to this to happen.

I get the cursor by using the code below:

```
def do_select(sql, db_conn):
    resultSet = None
    try:
        cursor = db_conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)

        resultSet = {
            "cursor": cursor,
            "columns": cursor.description
        }

    except Exception as error:
        print("An error occurred" + str(error))

    return resultSet
```

And **instead of** using this type of code:

```
resultSet = self.do_select(sql, self.get_db_conn())
rows = resultSet["cursor"].fetchAll()
for row in rows:
   # Do something...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
resultSet = self.do_select(sql, self.get_db_conn())
while resultSet.next():
   entire_row_tuple = resultSet.getCurrent() #I don't know if this is possible in python
   #Do something with entire_row_tuple...
```

Is this possible in python? Or, does exists a better way instead of using "fetchAll()" method?

Thank you

Comment: Check `fetchOne()` or `fetchMany()` - se e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26916459/4808122)