# pandas - cdecimal.ConversionSyntax invalidOperation on read_sql_query()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem with Pandas read_sql_query() function when working with database `decimal` data types. I have no issues with identical code below when working with `varchar` or `integer` types.

***Version Info:***

```
CentOS 6.6
Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda:
pandas                    0.16.2               np19py27_0
cdecimal                  2.3                      py27_0
pyodbc                    3.0.10                   py27_0
sqlalchemy                1.0.8                    py27_0
```

Below is my code reduced as much as possible to replicate the error.  I have also tried via sqlalchemy and have gotten the same error.  (There is no sqlalchemy engine for netezza so it still needs to rely on pyodbc.)

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd 
connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={NetezzaSQL};servername=nzserver;database=MASTER;username=USER_GUY;password=****")

sql = "select cast(0.0 as decimal(6,2)) as testing "

data = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=True)

#Also tried this, same error   
data = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=False)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidOperation                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-ba167303e6b2> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 data = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=True)
      3 # InvalidOperation: [<class 'cdecimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
      4
```

Comment: FYI, i also tried with `read_sql()`... same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i got Pandas `read_sql_query()` to work with a Netezza `decimal` data type.  I did this by switching from `pyodbc` to `pypyodbc` (described [here](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/)).

I noticed some strange things with unicode in results, so I passed a few extra params to the connection object in `pypyodbc` and now things seem to be working correctly.  I needed to change `unicode_results=False` and `ansi=true` (for DB output/messages)... but I think I am ok with that as my data should fit into ASCII and I'm not even sure how well NZ supports unicode anyway.

Working code below to get from a query to a `data.frame`:

```
import pypyodbc
import pandas as pd
connection = \
pypyodbc.connect(
    "Driver=NetezzaSQL;SERVERNAME=nzserver;DATABASE=MASTER;PORT=5480;USERNAME=user_guy;PASSWORD=******",
    ansi=True,
    unicode_results=False)

sql = """select 
            cast(0.0 as decimal(6,2))      as decimal_test, 
            cast(0 as integer)             as int_test, 
            cast('aosenuth' as varchar(5)) as varchar_test ,
            current_timestamp              as timestamp_test """
data = pd.io.sql.read_sql_query(sql, connection, index_col=None, coerce_float=True)

print data.shape
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=295) with pyodbc. There's a patch there you might try. There's even a comment there from netezza.

Comment: ugh, that's from 2012...  I'll pull the patch and see if i can cobble something together.

Comment: Good luck! If you get it working, consider putting your modified file on Github and putting a link to it back here.