# Formatting results from cursor.execute

Tags: python

I need help to have my results show as amount, amount_discounted and month in a table. I was able to do it in MySQL workbench but not through Python.
Here is my code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Importing connector

import mysql.connector
conn = None
#Opening a connection
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="Karimanzira1978!", database="classicmodels")
    print("Connected to MySQL!")
except Exception as ex:
    print ("cannot connect to MySQL : exception : " + str(ex))

# Setting a cursor

cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor2= conn.cursor()

c = conn.cursor()


cursor1.execute("SELECT sum(amount), sum(amount *.99) as discounted_amount, paymentDate from payments where paymentDate >= '2003-12-01' AND paymentDate <='2003-12-31'")

print(cursor2.fetchall())

cursor2.execute("SELECT sum(amount), sum(amount *.99) as discounted_amount, paymentDate from payments where paymentDate >= '2004-12-01' AND paymentDate <='2004-12-31'")


print(cursor2.fetchall())

conn.commit()

conn.close
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pandas` module's `DataFrame`

First: `python -m pip install -U pandas` to install pandas for your version of Python.

Second import it with `from pandas import DataFrame`.

Then, (using the second cursor as an example) store data from the .execute to a variable like so (just add r = infront of the cursor2.execute):

```
r = cursor2.execute("SELECT sum(amount), sum(amount *.99) as discounted_amount, paymentDate from payments where paymentDate >= '2004-12-01' AND paymentDate <='2004-12-31'")
```

Now, store the fetchall() into a dataframe:
    `df = DataFrame(r.fetchall())`

Last, set the columns of the dataframe:
    `df.columns = r.keys()`

You should be able to see the first 5 rows of the table with: `df.head()`

Referenced: [How to convert SQL Query result to PANDAS Data Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193/how-to-convert-sql-query-result-to-pandas-data-structure)

Answer (score 0):

Going forward, you might also want to take a look at the `pandas.read_sql` function ([documented here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)). You pass it a SQL query and a database connection and it does all the work of reading that into a Pandas dataframe for you!

For example:

```py
import mysql.connector
from pandas import read_sql

conn = None
#Opening a connection
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.Connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="Karimanzira1978!", database="classicmodels")
    print("Connected to MySQL!")
except Exception as ex:
    print ("cannot connect to MySQL : exception : " + str(ex))

query = "SELECT sum(amount), sum(amount *.99) as discounted_amount, paymentDate from payments where paymentDate >= '2003-12-01' AND paymentDate <='2003-12-31'"

df = read_sql(query, conn)
```