# Using Jupyter notebook to convert SQL into Panda Data Frame

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to fetch SQL Query to Pandas Data Frame using Jupyter Notebook.

**I followed [these instruction from beardc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487936/8305056):**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info) 
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Address 
WHERE City = 'Bothell' 
ORDER BY AddressID ASC"""
df = psql.frame_query(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

**However, whenever I run the code it shows:**

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-4ea4efb152fe> in <module>()
  1 import pandas as pd
  2 
  3 df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
  4 
  5 cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info)

NameError: name 'sql' is not defined
```

I'm using a monitored-network (company network if anyone asks).

**There are some questions I want to ask:**

1. Do I have to change the `connection_info` into the info in my database?
2. Is it important that I'm connected to a network that might have restriction on port connection? as the company sets up some of those.

I'm using the latest Anaconda Distribution.

Comment: in second line of code variable sql is not defined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is being caused by **the order** of your code:

```
1  import pandas as pd
2  df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)  ## You call the variable sql here, but don't assign it until line 6
3 
4  cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info) 
5  cursor = cnxn.cursor()
6  sql = """SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Address 
7  WHERE City = 'Bothell' 
8  ORDER BY AddressID ASC"""
9  df = psql.frame_query(sql, cnxn)
10 cnxn.close()
```

- You are calling the variable `sql` on line 2, but you don't actually define the variable until line 6.
- You are also missing a few libraries, and based off beardc's code it looks like you've meshed some of the wrong parts of his two answers together.

---

**Try arranging the code like this:**

*(Please note this code is untested, and the other issues described below)*

```
#Import the libraries
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
#Give the connection info
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info) 
#Assign the SQL query to a variable
sql = "SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.Person.Address WHERE City = 'Bothell' ORDER BY AddressID ASC"
#Read the SQL to a Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
```

---

**In answer to your questions:**

1. Yes, you need to change the connection_info to the info in your database. There is a good example of the text you need to put in there [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-2017)
2. This specific issue isn't being caused by your network restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will pay attention to my code order next time.

Comment: For example, if my database is AdventureWorks2012 then what should I change my `connection_info` into?

Comment: Please visit and read the link I've included in my answer under point 2