# How to write excel from mysql table data using python

Tags: python, mysql, excel

I am trying to insert data in Excel sheet by mysql table data.

```
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2005', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '0.00000', '2006', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '0.00000', '2007', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2008', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2012', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2014', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2015', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2016', 'Y'
'Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2017', 'Y'
'Building Blocks', 'Olefins', 'Ethylene', '5.00000', '2005', 'Y'
'Building Blocks', 'Olefins', 'Ethylene', '5.00000', '2006', 'Y'
```

like this table and want to fill this data in excel sheet.

excel format is :

```
                                    2005-Y  2006-Y  2007-Y  2008-Y  2009-Y  2010-Y  2011-Y  2012-Y  2013-Y  2014-Y  2015-Y  2016-Y  2017-Y 2018-Y 2019-Y

Feedstock                 Naphtha   5   0   0   5   -   -   -   5   -   5   5   5   5 - -
Building Blocks (a)Olefine Ethylene 5   5   5   5   -   -   -   5   -   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 - -
                          Propylene 5   5   5   5   -   -   -   5   -   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 - - 
                          Butadiene 5   5   5   5   -   -   -   5   -   2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 - -
```

I tried:

```
import pymysql
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import  Alignment, Font


sqlconn = ".............."
cursor = sqlconn.cursor()


wb = load_workbook('cpm_auto.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

max_col = (sheet.max_column)
max_row = (sheet.max_row)

for row in range(3,max_row):
    for col in range(4,max_col):
        periods = sheet.cell(row = 1,column = col).value
        period = periods.replace('-Y','')
        val = sheet.cell(row = row,column = 3).value
        if val == 'Naphtha':
            query = "select Value from CPMAI where Product = '%s' and Year = '%s'" %(val,period)
            result = cursor.execute(query)

            if result > 0:
                values = cursor.fetchone()
                if len(values) > 0:
                    prev_value = values[0]
                    print(prev_value)
                    sheet.cell(row = row,column = col).value = values[0]
                else:

                    sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value = prev_value
    break

wb.save('cpm_auto.xlsx')
```

My Code:
I tried This code but this code inserting value for the year which having values, but i want to insert all year value from 2005- 2019. please see excel format there is no values for 2009, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2018, 2019 so want to carry forward the previous year value to that year.

Comment: What you want to do is create a pivot table. Did you play with panda's pivot and pivot_table functions?

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it for above example

Comment: you question is a little too broad. You must load data from mysql, see e.g. https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/ then you have to create the pivot table, see e.g. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html You should try to write some code, so that we can help you

Comment: thanks  luca.vercelli. I edited the question with my code. I am too close but want to carry forward previous year data which year is not mention till 2019..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the data is in your database. If you follow the example below, you can

```
import xlwt


cols = [
    ['Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '5.00000', '2005', 'Y'],
    ['Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '0.00000', '2006', 'Y'],
    ['Feedstock', 'None', 'Naphtha', '0.00000', '2007', 'Y'],
    ['Building Blocks', 'Olefins', 'Ethylene', '5.00000', '2005', 'Y'],
    ['Building Blocks', 'Olefins', 'Ethylene', '5.00000', '2006', 'Y'],
]

res = {}
for c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 in cols:
    res_key = "{}-{}-{}".format(c1, c2, c3)
    year_key = "{}-{}".format(c5, c6)
    years = {"year": year_key, "value": c4}
    res.setdefault(res_key, []).append(years)

title = ["" for _ in range(3)]
_lst = [title]
is_first = True
for info, years in res.items():
    rows = [item if not item == "None" else "" for item in info.split("-")]
    for item in years:
        year = item["year"]
        value = int(float(item["value"]))
        rows.append(value)
        if is_first:
            title.append(year)
    is_first = False
    _lst.append(rows)

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
sheet = book.add_sheet('untitled', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

for row, rowdata in enumerate(_lst):
    for col, val in enumerate(rowdata):
        sheet.write(row, col, val)
book.save("test.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the computation *before* creating the excel sheet. For example (if the table is not too large):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load table into a DataFrame, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193
query = "select * from CPMAI"
result = cursor.execute(query)
df = pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall())
df.columns = result.keys()

pivot = df.pivot_table(values=["value"], index=["product"], columns=["year"], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Later, you can loop over the pivot elements and fill the Excel sheet