# How do I convert a database query to a data frame?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am executing a stored procedure to extract a resultset:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = 'EXEC [usp_PM_CalculateSLAForHelpDesk_Query_Details] @Param = {0}'.format(1111)
cursor.execute('[usp_PM_CalculateSLAForHelpDesk_Query_Details] ?', '1111') 
df= pd.read_sql(query,cnxn) 
cnxn.close()
```

I have a stored procedure with one parameter. So how should I proceed to extract the result set into a data frame?

Comment: See - for instance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193/how-to-convert-sql-query-result-to-pandas-data-structure

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html), you can use the `params=` argument

```
query = 'EXEC [usp_PM_CalculateSLAForHelpDesk_Query_Details] @Param = ?'
data = (1111, )
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params=data)
```