# List unique ID's with duplicate values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, unique

Im using SQL server in pyodbc and python. I want to create a list of lists, dictionary, or panda df etc. of unique ID's of rows with duplicate values in multiple columns. For ex. i have a table like this:

```
 ID          size      page       rate
12345         6         12         20  
67890         6         12         20
23456         4         10         15
87654         4         10         15
43210         4         10         15
....
```

Columns size, page, and rate are duplicates for rows 1-2, and 3-5. So I need to group the ID's together like so: (List of lists for example:)

```
duplicates = [[12345, 67890], [23456, 87654, 43210],...]
```

After my cursor executes and i get the first table as results:

```
duplicates =[]
row1 = [row[1] for row in cursor]
row2 = [row[1] for row in cursor]
counter = 1
index = 0
for row in cursor:
   if index <= len(row1)-2:
    n0 = row1[index]
    n1 = row2[index]
    n2 = row1[index+1]
    n3 = row2[index+1]
    if n0 == n1 and n2 == n3:
        duplicates.append(row[0])
    else:
        counter+=1
    index+=1
else: break
```

Not working but any help and guidance will be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Refer this post to read from [`SQL`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487936/4985099) followed by, ``df.groupby(['size','page','rate'])['ID'].apply(list).tolist()``

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the query result into a pandas dataframe (let's say name 'df'). After which you can extract the duplicates id using following line.

`df1 = df.groupby('size')['ID'].apply(list).reset_index(name='duplicates')`