# what should be changed to make this model as a real time model between mysql and python pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

so i have a model in pandas python from csv that i process in MySQL first.

here's my query before i transform it into CSV files.

```
SELECT om.id AS id_pesanan,
omd.id AS order_match_detail_id,
p.name nama_produk, 
FLOOR(omd.quantity / pp.pack_size) AS total_kemasan,
omd.createdAt AS tanggal_pemesanan,
omd.price * pp.pack_size AS harga_per_pcs,
omd.createdby AS user,
awb.customer_regency AS lokasi
FROM order_match om 
JOIN order_match_detail omd ON om.id = omd.order_match_id
JOIN product p ON p.id = omd.product_id
JOIN packs pp ON omd.pack_id = pp.id
JOIN air_way_bills awb ON om.code_order = awb.code_order 
WHERE om.order_status_id IN (4,5,6,8) 
GROUP BY om.id;
```

and i save it into CSV with name `rfm_machine_learning2`

after that I transform it into CSV, and i call it using pandas to make machine learning models

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\rfm_machine_learning2.csv')
```

what i want to know is, i want to make it real time models, every day in 01:00 PM that models being build, so that means for everyday, the models run, how do i do that? i've just wondering with make an event in mysql for every 01:00 PM everyday, but idk next step after that?

Comment: Why aren't you querying mysql directly? Anyway, this is not real time, this sounds like a daily batch job, which you can take care of via your favourite task scheduler. Operating systems usually have one built-in.

Comment: because in ```mysql``` its just only produce the data, in ```pandas``` i build the models that comes from the csv from ```mysql```, lets say,  the model cant be build in directly in ```mysql```

Comment: after ```df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\rfm_machine_learning2.csv')``` there will be another next step.

Comment: but I agree with you, it's not real-time, it's a daily batch job.

Comment: My point was that pandas can connect to mysql directly and retrieve the data, rather than export the data to csv and import it from there to pandas.

Comment: im sorry im new into pandas, can you suggest me what should i do in answer section?

Comment: Or just could use existing answers in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047193/how-to-convert-sql-query-result-to-pandas-data-structure

Comment: Thank you, and how to make it so the model will automatically run for everyday