# Getting a "TypeError: an integer is required" when trying to connect to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql-python

Total Python newb here.

I'm following the tutorial from [this page](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).  But when I run my code I get the following error in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tejenshrestha/Documents/ProjectAccess/access/trunk/analysis/src/json_xml/Database.py", line 37, in <module>
    con = MySQLdb.connect(socket, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Searching some solutions I found required that the unix_socket path to be include, which I did as you can see.

I'm also using **XAMPP** and the socket path I'm using is the one specified in XAMPP's my.cnf file.  I have MySQL running and the port it is 3306.

Please help out this noob.

The Python code:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

con = None
dbhost = "localhost"
port   = "3306"
dbuser = "root"
dbpass = "password"
dbname = "name"
socket = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock"

try:
    con = MySQLdb.connect(socket, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

    data = cur.fetchone()
    print "Database version : %s " % data

except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:    
    if con:    
        con.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the quotes from around port and see if that works.

---

```
<brilliant code>
port = 3306
<brilliant code>
```

---

I think you need to label the arguments in your connect function, see the top answer here:

[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: I tried that previously an got and error like: `argument 3 must be of type String`.  I tried rearranging the order of the parameters so that socket and port (port being a number) are the last parameters and still get the same error.  Not sure if I'm ordering the arguments correctly.

Comment: Hmm. You shouldn't change the order of the arguments unless you label them, so your function call would look like `MysqlDB.connect(port=3306, ...)`. So try labeling the arguments of your function with their proper names.

Comment: No problem, @icanc. You should click through the link and upvote the original answer, too.