# how to connect a python code to database using mysql

Tags: python

I am using below code for connectivity:

```
    import MySQLdb



db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","test" )


cursor = db.cursor()


cursor.execute("SELECT * from student")


data = cursor.fetchone()
print "Database result : %s " % data


db.close()
```

i am getting  below error during running the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/xsxs.py", line 5, in <module>
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","test" )
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

How can i solve it.

Comment: Are your database/server credentials correctly written? Try running "mysql -u root -p root" in the shell and tell us what you see. Then try "use test" in the mysql shell and check if you can select your database.

Comment: Your code is attempting to connect to a mySQL server running on the same computer as the python code.  If that's what you wanted then most likely, your database on the local machine is not running and you need to start it before running the python code.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be that no mysql server is running on your windwos host. You either have to install it (http://www.mysql.de/why-mysql/windows/) or have to choose another server like

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("my_mysql_host.mydomain.tld","root","root","test" )
```

Thats it.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Check you connectionstring:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="username", # your username
                      passwd="Pswrd", # your password
                      db="MyDB") # name of the data base
```

This SO will help you:

[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql connector using pip,

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Sample code to connect a local database named TCS and select data from table named student,

```
import mysql.connector    
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='TCS')

try:
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   cursor.execute("select * from student")
   result = cursor.fetchall()
   print result
finally:
    cnx.close()
```