# How to make simple sql modifications from shell?

Tags: programming-languages, sql, linux

I have never made any software for linux, but it would be better for me now. I would like to write a simple `SQL modification` software that I can `run via terminal` and don't need to run php, apache. (`withouth apache`)

Could someone convert me this:

```
<?php

$le = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_table WHERE alfa="0"');
while ($i = mysql_fetch_assoc($le))
{
  $le2 = mysql_num_rows('SELECT * FROM tbl_table3 WHERE t1id="'.$i["id"].'"');
  if ($le2 > 0)
 {
 mysql_query('UPDATE tbl_table SET num="'.$le2.'" WHERE id="'.$i["id"].'"');
 }
}
?>
```

Or can anyone `give me a tutorial` for how I could write it for a shell command, or something that can be started from terminal? Or what is the English name of what I'm looking for? (linux debian)

Comment: You are aware that PHP does *not* need a web server, right?  Run your php script via the command line, "php myscript.php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat, but I'd go with a Python script.

Since you're running Linux you'll already have Python on the system. You'll need to install a MySQL driver such as MySQLdb and then just convert your simple PHP script to Python.

There's an excellent answer which covers what you'll need to know (and more) here: [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python).