# Python MySQL won't work

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I installed python mysqldb with command: apt-get install python-mysqldb, everything was fine but I cannot open any python script with:

```
 import mysqldb
```

I still get information:

```
ImportError: No module named mysqldb
```

Any idea what to do? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the module is `MySQLdb` not `mysqldb`, so try instead:

```
import MySQLdb
```

But you really could have found the mistake on your own within a minute with the help of a quick Google search...

(see also: [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python))