# Connecting to MySQL db via python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to a mysql db. I have installed the mysqldb package but it still says 'ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb' when I import.

Why?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.04, sorry I am new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without more detail! Have a look at these:

There's a pretty comprehensive guide for the installation (on Python 3) of the mysql connector here:

[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Perhaps thats worth another try. Alternatively I have happily used the mysql.connector which I got from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Its written in python so may be slower than the first option, which you may or may not care about.