# Connector/Python works with Mavericks?

Tags: python, mysql, osx-mavericks, connector

I'm looking for a database connection for Python 3.3.3rc1 and MySQL 5.6.15 (10.7 64-bit dmg). I installed Connector/Python 1.1.4. I've OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks). Works fine with Python 2.7.

When I try to import mysql.connector I got the error ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

Should Connector work with this composition?

Comment: This may help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: I found that page earlier and installed MySQLdb for Python 2.7 but did not work either. Somewhere it was said MySQL-python 1.2.4 works not more than MySQL 5.5. And python 3 does not support MySQLdb.

Comment: There may be something as I had with Connector/Python 1.1.4 dmg-packet from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/. To get work with Python 2.7 download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python and use this install instructions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source-unix.html