# How to wrap mysql in a python script

Tags: python, mysql

*I want to write a wrapper script around the mysql `cli client.` So I can construct the `mysql cli flags` to be used based on some logic.*

***my question is:***

*How would I execute the mysql client so that the user can interact with it.* (***stdout,stdin forwarded etc***)?

Comment: Perhaps a better title for your question is "How to wrap a process in a python script"

Comment: Ah I thought of that initially, but then I thought mentioning mysql would be more specific

Comment: [Effective dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python). I'm pretty sure you just want to connect and run queries.

Comment: @U2EF1, no this is not a duplicate. He wants his users to be able to run queries *interactively*.

Comment: @wjimenez5271, I think what you will wind up with is a lot of people saying "uh duh, MySQLDB, or PyMySQL", with realizing your real problems is "forwarding" stin/stdout.

Comment: Is the idea just to launch the mysql client and then hand over control, or do you want python to interact with mysql?

Comment: @PeterGibson Just launch and hand over control

Comment: @PaulDraper Thanks for pointing out how the question comes across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build your list of arguments and use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to launch MySQL

```
import subprocess

args = ['-u', 'wjimenez5271', '-p']
subprocess.call('mysql', args)
print('done')
```

This will launch `mysql -u wjimenez5271 -p`, handing over control until the process terminates, then python will resume and print "done".