# How to check if pyodbc is already installed on my MacOS?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, odbc

Is there any way to check if pyodbc is already installed in my MacOS (10.9)? I already had python 2.7 installed on my mac and in addition I installed python3 later. Now both version of the python works fine from my terminal.

I heard pyodbc will not work alone and it  needs a odbc manager (and the recommended is iodbc for mac), is there any  way for that to check as well? Me kind of new to these things and so do not intend to create mess by installing another pyodbc or iodbc which is already there on my mac.

Not sure if this info is relevant, but i want to create a database connection using ODBC that has to work both for MySQL and Postgres (I have them both installed on my mac), select some info from a table and close the connection. And right now I am on my first phase of creating a connection..

Helps will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally a good way to see if a python lib is installed is to go the the python prompt and attempt to import it

```
>>import pyodbc
```

Obviously, you could use find, locate, etc, but this will tell you if it is installed and working properly.

You asked about pyodbc, and generally you shouldn't give answers based on opinions on SO, but I have worked a fair bit with psycopg2 for Postgres and found it easier to use and more reliable than pyodbc. I haven't used Python with MySQL, but there are good reports for [MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

I mention this because you say you are at early stages, so it might be worth considering the native drivers for each DB.

Comment: @rubiksKube you are welcome. Did you get pyodbc working OK, and did you try either of the Postgres or Mysql drivers. I tried pyodbc to connect to SQL Server, but couldn't get it working on linux, though I could on windows.