# python inserting into mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

I am trying to work out what is wrong with my code.  I am trying to enter data into a mysql, and python doesn't seem to like how i have done something.

Test Data

```
Name = "TestRegion"
Perent= "perent"
x1 = -100.0
x2 = -150.0
z1 = 94.0
z2 = 200.0
```

Code

```
def NewRegion(Name, Perent, x1, x2, z1, z2):
  try:
    con = SQLConnect()
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = """INSERT INTO RegionName (Name, Perent, X1, X2, Z1, Z2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"""
    cur.execute(sql, (Name, Perent, x1, x2, z1, z2))
    con.commit()

  except mdb.Error, e:
    con.rollback()
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])

  finally:           
    if con:    
        con.close()
```

my issue I am guessing is how I am trying to pass the values to the sql statment.

my Error message is

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py, line 159, in execute
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: do u want know other way of same implementation which is easy

Comment: yeah, always up for another way.

Comment: u can use peeweee.. easy library .. http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/installation.html for all sort of database actions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    sql = u'INSERT INTO RegionName (Name, Perent, X1, X2, Z1, Z2) VALUES ("%s","%s",%d,%d,%d,%d)'% (Name, Perent, x1, x2, z1, z2)
    cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: thanks, what does the u at the front of the sql statement do?

Comment: u'' is used for utf-8 encoding string if you use a string that have special character like è é ecc.. this prevents encoding problems

Comment: This is **wrong**. You've now totally unnecessarily opened yourself up to SQL injection attacks. Do not do this.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL adapter does not use `?` for placeholders, it uses `%s`.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO RegionName (Name, Perent, X1, X2, Z1, Z2) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
cur.execute(sql, (Name, Perent, x1, x2, z1, z2))
```

Comment: I can only pass a max of 4 arguments.  but thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know what that means. There are six arguments here.