# Connect OpenERP with mysql using cr?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I would like to get some data from mysql in OpenERP.

In one way I can do it like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

# connect
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="appuser", passwd="",
db="onco")

cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM LOCATION")

# commit your changes
db.commit()

# get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)

# get and display one row at a time.
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[0], "-->", row[1]
```

from [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

But is it maybe smarter way to do it? To use cr like standard OpenERP object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is ok, but:

1. You don't need `db.commit()` after `SELECT`. It's necessary only if you change something in database.
2. Instead of getting the number of rows and `for x in range(0, numrows)` you can use `for x in cursor.fetchall():`. To get only `n` elements you can use `cursor.fetchmany(n)`.