# calling a mysql and printing data matching text file(python)

Tags: php, python, mysql

I know to connect to a db and connected it and i done it by

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root", # your username
                      passwd="mysql", # your password
                      db="sakila") # name of the data base
```

I have a text file qwer.txt
                                                                                             i have the table name:vehicle

I need to perform the operation which is to print words that match the text file and database.my operation for a small db and small file is given by this but what about connecting the database and matching them?

```
    mysql_row = "car,bike"
    file_str = "I have a car"

    mysql_elements = mysql_row.split(",")
    file_elements = file_str.split(" ")

    output_array = []

    for m_element in mysql_elements:
        for i in range(len(file_elements)):
            if ((m_element == file_elements[i]) and (i < len(file_elements)-1)):
               output_array.append(file_elements[i])

    print output_array
```

Output:car

So,what are the changes to be done for connecting the database directly and the filename to perform the matching operation.

Comment: table name where u have key words

Comment: vehicle is the table name

Comment: do u want know how to retreive the values from table and search right?

Comment: yes of course,please help.

Comment: have u seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: of course,i saw it and made it,but it doesnot tell how to search the db and search with the txt file.

Comment: do u want to searcha file  using the car names in database

Comment: yes,that what i am looking for.

Comment: yes i am testing it,a small doubt can it be done for large database files too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM Vehicle")

# commit your changes
db.commit()

keywords=[]
```

here fetchall() gets all the rows and we append carnames to key words

```
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])

with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
```

this is used to open a file

```
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
                print line
```

for each word in keywords search the line brings our output

Comment: with open('qwer.txt','r') as file: this is the error i get,what is 'r' used for?