# how to access south created tables from django views?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have a django south created table "tablename", I want to acess it from django views, like this.

```
from myapp.models import*
def function(request):
    a=Tablename.objects.all()
    return
```

but this shaows an error "global name 'Tablename' is not defined"
can anyone help me to access south created table from django views.
thanks

Comment: What do you mean "south created"? If there is no model for this table you have to make sql queries yourself else be sure that `from myapp.models import*` imports `Tablename`

Comment: south created means there is no model in models.py but table is created using django south

Comment: if there is no relation between table and django, so you have to make queries yourself; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: its postgres i'm using

Comment: :D I haven't use it so far but maybe this helps; https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python