# Specifying Table to Connect to with Python Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

I have read the [Peewee MySQL API documentation](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/database.html#using-mysql) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python); however, what I do not understand is how to connect to a specified table in a db using Peewee. Essentially all I'm trying to do is connect to a a table called `Persons` in a db called `as_schema`, set up some sort of basic object-relational mapping, and print out all entries' `aNum` column values.

My table `Persons` that I'm trying to read from has the following columns:

- varchar called `aNum`
- bool called `access`
- bool called `ajar`
- bool called `ebr`
- date called `weekof`

My code consists of the following:

```
import peewee
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('as_schema', user='root',passwd='')#this connection path works perfectly, tried it using the standard MySQLdb.connect

class Person(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(Person):
    aNum = CharField()

Person.create_table()
person = User(aNum = 'a549189')
person.save();

for person in Person:
    print person.aNum
```

The error I'm getting is:
[image]

Comment: So far what I've found is that maybe using Pwiz and the migrate function may be a good idea http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Person(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        db_table = 'Persons'  # Add this.
```

In the docs, you can find a list of supported meta options:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options-and-table-metadata