# Python equivalnt for a dbq?

Tags: python

With bash I can extract the whole database with this command:

```
DataBaseQuery="SELECT * FROM my_database_list.database"
mysql -uUSER -p'PASSWORD'<< EndOfFile 
$DataBaseQuery
EndOfFile
```

What would be the python equivalent of this command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Create a new process with the provided arguments:
# - the command itself and its arguments as a list
# - create a new pipe for STDIN and STDOUT and STDERR
cmd = Popen(
    ['mysql', '--user=USER', '--password=Password'],
    stdin=PIPE,
    stdout=PIPE,
    stderr=PIPE,
)

# Feed the query into STDIN and read STDOUT/STDERR into
# the appropriate variables, which are returned as strings
stdout, stderr = cmd.communicate(
    'SELECT * FROM my_database_list.database'
)
```

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning `subprocess.check_output()`, which raises an exception on error.

Comment: But then you can't use `Popen.communicate` since `check_output` is a blocking call.

Comment: [check_output](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) accepts `input` as an argument.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini heh - I didn't realize that. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output(
    ['mysql', '-uUSER', '-pPASSWORD'],
    input=b'SELECT * FROM ...')
```

You must be aware of a problem, however: both with this solution and with the Bash solution, you are specifying the password on the command line. An unprivileged user may use `ps` to get the password of your database, thus decreasing security.

Also, note that with Python you can choose from a number of database drivers (such as [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)) and Object Relational Mappers (such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)). These drivers/ORMs solve the password problem and offer you easy ways to parse results from queries, along with other benefits.

Check out [this example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) from MySQL offical documentation to see how convenient a database driver is.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `ps` issue - I noticed that too but forgot to mention it in my answer. I believe the `mysql` command will read the password from STDIN if the password is not included and the `-p` flag is supplied.

Comment: @NathanOsman: actually I believe that `mysql` reads from the tty, rather than from the standard input, to avoid echoing the password to the terminal.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's good to know. It looks like Python provides a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html) for creating a process and obtaining access to its TTY. But as you've mentioned - it's probably easier to use one of the many Python MySQL libraries.