# Flask CRUD programming without SQLAlchemy or other ORM

Tags: python, mysql, flask, orm, sqlalchemy

I am learning Python / Flask. Now I am at the point where I am learning Flask with MySQL Database. I read lots of posts about using Flask with databases and most of them suggest to use SQLAlchemy. I tried to read about SQLAlchemy, but I didn't like that because I prefer building and executing SQL queries and creating tables in the database only. Is there any way that I can take full benefit of using Flask with MySQL Database without SQLAlchemy?

Please suggest.

Comment: Great question. I love SQL and lean on the side of those who think that [ORM is an anti-pattern](http://seldo.com/weblog/2011/08/11/orm_is_an_antipattern). I've been looking for a way to use a framework for user management and form-generation without "giving away the keys to the database".

Comment: You specifically mention the "full benefit of using Flask." As a warning to new users coming across this question, it's important to know that many popular Flask extensions either assume you'll be using SQLAlchemy or even Flask-SQLAlchemy, or at the very least, that you have your data structured in the form of classes (roughly representing tables) which are used to create objects (representing rows), e.g., `new_user = User(name="John", email="john@mail.com")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use SQLAlchemy, no. You just have to connect to the database in Flask and execute your queries manually.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) is about how to connect to MySQL with Python, and the [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/) go over [creating a site with a SQLite database](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/setup/#tutorial-setup). Modify the examples provided there with your MySQL connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to join the tables and retrieve the data with flask other than injecting the SQL query directly?