# mysql to pdf - python or ruby

Tags: python, mysql, ruby, pdf

i have a mysql database that i'd like to query. i would like to format the results a certain way, then turn it into a pdf. in the past, i used PHP and FPDF, while it worked, it was a pain and tedious. i don't think PHP can handle this sort of thing. i don't have much experience in python or ruby but this would be a great project to do in either language so i can get more familiar. it doesn't have to be web based. it can be desktop script that i could run with a cron or manually. hope someone can point me to some resources. thanks.

Comment: sure there are many libraries for mysql in python and many libraries for pdf (they all are kind of a pain) ... all you need to do is combine one from each set and write some code

Comment: @joran is there one you prefer over another?

Comment: most people use mysqldb(although its kinda tough to setup on windows) ... pypdf is the only pdf libray i have messed with ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley great i'll check that out. i'm on osx so it shouldn't be an issue. otherwise i'll run a vm with linux. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby you have a number of options for your PDF authoring, and your DB management is very easy if you use the ActiveRecord library (comes with Rails) or [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) to read or write data.

Complete and heavy duty PDF authoring can be done using [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/)... it requires some studying, but it's an amazing library.

You can also create HTML web pages and convert them into PDF using the [wicked_pdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf), which is quite simple to use.

Or, you can combine it all, or write simple PDF's with simple tables and text using the [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf), which is as easy as it gets and also allows you to use PDF templates (so you can have a well designed template and just add the text you need).

I love Ruby and I think it's very easy to learn. Plus, it has more applications than just web programming - there's even a project called [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com) which lets you program native applications for iOS and Android using Ruby!

I'm sure you'll love Ruby.

Comment: great! thanks for the links. i have some stuff to mess with this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can use [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) to create PDF files. As for the querying a mySQL DB, you can use [mySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/3302584). Installing it is slightly harder than other modules, but once you have done so, it's just like any other sql package. Hope it helped.

Comment: thanks, i will check those out. i think i know about the challenge with mysql and python. at least i ran into one that relates to the driver. but eventually i was able to figure it out. not sure if it's similar with this library. i'll play with these 2 and update once i get results.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Remember to accept answers that worked for you. @w1n78