# MySQL connector in centOS 7

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to deploy a flask app in a centOS 7.

I installed the connector with: `sudo yum install mysql-connector-python`

But when I run: `python init.py`, I got this error:

```
from mysql import connector
ImportError: No module named mysql
```

Note: my project is inside a virtualenv.

Inside my virtualenv:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Error:`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MySQL-python in /root/ams/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

```
yum install MySQL-python
```

Error:`Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-11.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: it looks like something is not right when you install the `mysql-connector-python` package. Try follow my edited answer below to find out whether the `mysql` python package is in the `sys.path`.

Comment: when I type sudo python app.py, the adapter is imported, but without sudo python can't find the package. Its virtualenv problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can run this :

```
sudo yum install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the reason but probably the mysql connector you installed is not imported into your virtualenv.

Do the following to see the lib paths:

```
(virtualenv) $ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

And search for each path for `mysql` directory.

**UPDATE**

If you decide to use `MySQL-python` instead of `mysql-connector-python` you can follow its document [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

My recommendation is to use some db layer like `SQLAlchemy` but if you want to connect to mysql manually here's a good tutorial.

[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: Doesn't exist any mysql directory. But when I run pip install MySQL-python, appears: MySQL-python in /root/ams/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages. So its installed, how I use it?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't explain clearly -- the `sys.path` will output a list of paths and you have to check each path manually (in the terminal use `cd` and `ls`) for the `mysql` dir. The most likely path is 1) your virtualenv/lib/python27/site-packages 2) /usr/lib/python27/site-packages. First look for `mysql` in these two places

Comment: I just found mysql in /usr/lib/python27/site-packages. In virtualenv I found a different mysql distribution - MySQLdb