# Python function to select records from a mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, database, function

I created a table with 100 records and now i want to generate a python function which takes a number and the table name and pulls records from the referenced table. ie. function should selects 'n' records from specified table.

I have already stated querying the database using python scripts. I can do a regular select but every time i want to select i have to edit the query. Is there a way for me to write a function in python that would take two parameters; eg.(n, table) that will allow me to select n records from any table in my database?

Is this possible and if it is where should i start?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/2932244)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: Not sure if you sent the correct link. I already started writing to and querying the database using python scrips. I am able to do a select from but i need something dynamic/flexible and not hard coded.

Comment: see additional comments @JRodDynamite

Comment: not a duplicate of the link you sent @ojii please see additional comments for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below function

```
def query_db( no_of_rows, table_name ):
  cur = db.cursor()
  query = """
    select top %d rows from %s
  """ %( int(no_of_rows), table_name )
  cur.execute(query)
  for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

Is this what you want, or am i missing something?

Comment: I had to tweek the query a little because im using MySQL. However the this error pops up when i try to call the function (name 'rooms' is not defined). The name of the table is rooms. I am trying to resolve it with assigning a table name to it statically. @Shrey