# Python to Mysql in AWS

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I have mysql in my computer and have a table called Login hosted in Amazon AWS. The url from the AWS is in the form of

```
url:Port/Database_name
```

I am unable to connect to AWS database from python code using mysql connector. I am able to do it with my Java program though.

Comment: ok so rule out aws security groups right?

Comment: yeap..I did rule it out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/622308

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Show the code you are using to connect with.

Comment: I am Unable to connect to AWS. I get Can't connect to MySQL server on 'url:3306' (111 Connection refused) as error