# python TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Tags: python

i'm new at python i tried to run the following

```
from distutils.util import execute
from gi.repository import Gtk
import mysql.connector

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
con = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='mydatabase')
sql = con.cursor()
test = Gtk.Button(label="test")
    save_buy.connect("clicked", self.test_click)
    box1.pack_start(test, True, True, 0)
def test_click(self, widget):
    self.sql = execute("SHOW TABLES")
    print(self.sql.fetchall())
```

and when i click on test button i get

```
TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

Comment: Your connector is missing :

try

sql.execute("SHOW TABLES");

Comment: Why are you using `distutils`?  Is that just something you found by searching for `execute`?  It has nothing to do with `mysql`.  And not something I'd expect a beginner to use either.

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty clear. You have to pass an other argument to `execute`.

Note that you are importing `execute` from `distutils.util`. The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.ccompiler.CCompiler.execute):

> `execute(func, args[, msg=None, level=1])`
>
> Invokes `distutils.util.execute()`. This method invokes a Python function `func` with the given arguments `args`, after logging and taking
>   into account the `dry_run` flag.

Moreover you are passing a string instead of a callable. You are probably confusing that execute function with an other function from the `mysql` package which accepts SQL statements.  For example the cursor has a `execute` *method*, so you maybe wanted to do `sql.execute("SHOW TABLES")` instead.

Comment: i need the execute of mysql and i can not find in the package to add to my project

Comment: @HussainAli Did you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/372885/510937    ?