# Python MySQLdb Connection Import Error

Tags: python, mysql, dbconnection

I am trying to connect with db using the following code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="root",  # your password
                     db="test101")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test1")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]

db.close()
```

However, I am getting the following error message on the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JRambo\workspace\DBConnection\src\DBConnection.py", line 6, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have followed the steps meticulously.
[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python/622308#622308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to verify that you have the correct bit Python and correct bit `MySQLdb`. If you have 32 bit Python and 64 bit `MySQLdb` it won't work. I had a similar problem with the same Traceback error and when I installed the correct bit type of each application, bingo! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!! I just realized that

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.