# Get database from LibreOffice Base with python

Tags: python, database, libreoffice-base

I would like to make a Database editable with LibreOffice Base and usable with python. I can't find a way with the normal HSQLDB as it requires Java (I would as less as possible dependencies) and the same thing with SQLite3 as it requires the drivers for LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use a split database setup, rather than the default embedded setup.  Otherwise it will crash a lot.

One solution that does not require Java is to switch to a different DB engine, for example MySQL.  With this setup, see [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)  LibreOffice Base works well with MySQL.

See also https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#Do_I_need_Java_to_use_Base.3F.  Split databases are discussed on that page as well.

Comment: Thanks! That exactly what I'm looking, but I don't want a service running in the background, just a file containing the database, like a SQLite, editable by LibreOffice.

Comment: Reading throughout the FAQ you posted, I found what I wanted: a flat-file database. I think I will use dBase files, or do you suggest something else?

Comment: dBase files have some big limitations.  As explained in [this PDF document](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/8/83/BH3502-CreatingADatabase.pdf), dBase files cannot have keys, and so relations are not supported from LO Base.  Perhaps SQLite would better suit your needs.  On a positive note, in my testing dBase files seem to be more stable than using an embedded setup.