# Object orientated function parameter to alter variables

Tags: python, function, oop, parameters

I am trying convert my program to an object orientated style. Currently, I have a brandSelector() function which takes the query input and finds an intersection between the query and the brands array. However, I am trying to convert the brandSelector() to a generic Selector() or intersection finder. For example, I could call with type and the query (Selector(type, query)). In this instance you would type Selector(brand, query). That additional parameter defines which array is checked and which variable is set - alternatively, an if statement would suffice - but I am not sure how to implement such a system. I would appreciate any solutions or advice. Thanks,

```
brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
brand = None

def Main():
    query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()
    brand = brandSelector(query)

def brandSelector(query):
    try:
        brand = set(brands).intersection(query.split())
        brand = ', '.join(brand)
        #Check Condition After Setting
        int_cond = confirmIntersection(brand)
        if int_cond == False:
            raise NameError("No Intersection")
        return brand
    except NameError:
        print("\nNo Intersection found between query defined brand and brands array\n")
        return brandDetectionFailure()
```

Full Code: https://github.com/KentCoding/phoneTroubleshooting/blob/master/phoneTroubleshooting.py
Python Version: v3.5.2

My Attempt:

```
def Main():
    init()
    query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()
    brand = Selector(brand, brands, query)
    keywordSelection(query, brand)
def Selector(var, array, query):
    try:
        #Format Brands Query
        var = set(array).intersection(query.split())
        var = ', '.join(var)
        #Check Condition After Setting
        int_cond = confirmIntersection(var)
        if int_cond == False:
            raise NameError("No Intersection")
        return var
    except NameError:
        print("\nNo Intersection found between query defined brand and brands array\n")
        return brandDetectionFailure()
```

But gives the error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'brand' referenced before assignment`

Comment: The error is because the statement `brand = Selector(brand, brands, query)` attempts to use `brand` by passing it as an argument to the `Selector()` function before it's defined.

Comment: Surely, it would not be a problem as I have defined it as a global with `brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
brand = None` However, if this does not work, how may I fix it? Thanks for your help

Comment: Legend - Thank you! :-) If you put it as an answer, I'm happy to give it a tick if you would like the rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, there's no reason to have the argument named  `var` being passed to `Selector()`, so just make it `def Selector(array, query):` and call it with `brand = Selector(brands, query)`.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, inside the `main()` function `brand` is considered to be a local variable because it's being assigned a value (the result of calling `Selector()`) and there's no preceding `global brand` statement before that point in the function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: IMO It's a bit more than a "tip" because it's important to understand that Python is executing your `def` before the byte code generated from doing that is itself ever executed. This means that when it encountered the `Selector(brand, brands, query)` call all it knew was that the variable `brand` had not been declared `global` (so it must be local) and had not been bound to [i.e. assigned] a value yet.

Comment: Does this mean you cannot simply define a global outside any of the functions? Therefore, you must reference the global within the function? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Also, as a Python expert, you wouldnt know if it is possible to print a array's variable name having assigned an array using a variable, for example:

    brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
In this instance print `'brands'` rather than `'["apple", "android", "windows"]'`

Thanks,

Comment: Using a `global` statement outside a function or method doesn't do anything (although no error message occurs). All variables assigned a value in a function will cause a local variable to be created if it doesn't already exist. To prevent this, you must declare it as a `global` in the function before any such assignment takes place—so I guess that counts as the "reference" you're talking about.

Comment: Printing `brands` is a reference—not an assignment—to it, so Python resolves its value using the [LEGB Rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules/292502#292502).

Comment: Ok - that makes sense. It is very kind of you for providing such a level of depth. Thank you. May I ask how you could then print the variable name of an array?

Comment: Values don't know what their names are (they may have more than one or even be anonymous, in fact). There are some hacks that can look for a name associated with a given value in the various LEGB scopes, but it's generally considered a poor practice. You could pass the variable name as a hardcoded string to `Selector()` as another argument if you wished.

Comment: Great, thank you - I will try it as an argument. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121464/discussion-between-sammy-herring-and-martineau).