# Python program login with database

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm writing a Python program that is NOT on a website; It is run on the user computer. Is there a way to make a username and password login to the program that doesn't have the username and password built into the source code where anyone can access it. I have a wordpress site that has user accounts. Can I access that database maybe? I'm not really sure how you would go about doing this so any direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: Yes sort of. Thanks. But how do I connect to my website's sql database without giving whoever is using my program access to my sites database? I just want them to put in a username and password and for my program to check it against the database to see if they match. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well if I'm understanding you correctly. You want a login system? Client side, let them enter their username and password, and it get sent to your server which then in your code you check if it's correct or not. They won't have access to your program, since it's server side. Unless you want to give them your program and then they enter the username and password as inputs, well then you need to make your program as a exe. I'm not 100% sure if that will work though for the latter.

Comment: So where and how do I make the server side program? I tried for about a week to convert my program to an exe but pyinstaller wasn't working and py2exe was having issues with selenium which I am using in a different part of my program. So is there a way for the client side script to take username and password as input and send it to my server side program? And thanks so much for your help by the way.