# python issue with popen and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, popen

I'm new to Python, and haven't used Linux in years, so I'm not sure where I'm getting tangled up. I'm trying to use Popen to run sql files in MySQL on Ubuntu.

Here is the relevant code:

```
command = ['mysql', '-uUSER', '-pPWD','-h192.168.1.132',  '--database=dbName', '<', './1477597236_foo.sql' ]
print("command is: "+subprocess.list2cmdline(command))

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='.'
)
```

the output from this is the same as if had run 'mysql --help'. The puzzling thing to me is that if i take the command output by subprocess.list2cmdline and run it directly, it runs perfectly. Also, if i replace `'< file.sql'` with `'-e select * from foo'`, it runs. So, the `'<'` and file are causing my problem. I know WHAT is causing the problem, but nothing I've tried so far has fixed it.

tia, Craig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a redirection or pipe or built-in command is present in the command line, `shell=True` is required. However, in simple cases like this, `shell=True` is overkill. There's a much cleaner way in order to avoid `shell=True` which gives better control on the input file.

- if the input file doesn't exist, you get an exception *before* reaching the subprocess, which is easier to handle
- the process runs without the shell: better portability & performance

the code:

```
command = ['mysql', '-uUSER', '-pPWD','-h192.168.1.132',  '--database=dbName' ]

with open('./1477597236_foo.sql') as input_file:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        command, stdin = input_file, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
    output,error = proc.communicate()
```

(I added the next line which should be a `communicate` call: since both stdout & stderr are redirected, it's the only simple way to avoid deadlocks between both output streams)

Comment: And the final option is to not use `subprocess` at all:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python

Comment: Typical me: answering at low-level, overlooking the big picture. Still my answer covers the case when input redirection is needed on a command, sql or other. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add `shell=True` to your `Popen` call.  `<` is a part of the shell and you can't use shell features without that parameter.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen( command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='.',shell=True )
```