# mySQLdb import error

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I am following this guide: [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)
running jupyter notebook.

I am running windws 10 operating system and I have installed MySQLdb from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/ "MySQL for python"

I have MySQL Workbench installed.

When running I get an error

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a07af86e2020> in <module>()
---> 12 import MySQLdb

ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I tried things such as

```
pip install mysqlclient
pip install mysql-python
```

Running mysqlclient gives me following:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-TH5iAY/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Running mysql-python gives me following:

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-anTaSr/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

When looking up the error on stack, it tells me to install MySQLdb, but I have that installed already.

Comment: pip install MySQL-python

Comment: The spelling also matters.

Comment: Doesn't change a thing

Comment: can you please mention the python version you were using?

Comment: The version is 2.7.6

Comment: In some cases specifying the version will works,,please try this too  pip install mysqlclient==1.3.4

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: If so please download the mysql connector for windows and install it. then try installing the python module

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Comment: I did that already. Didn't work.
BUT.. I got it to work. Since I am running a jupyter notebook I wrote this in the terminal:

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: what does it returns?