# Select a random row from the table using Python

Tags: python, database, random

Below is the my table.I use MySQL for the database queries.

**Structure of the table**

[image]

I want to print questions randomly by taking the questions from the table. How can I do that using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint
num = randint(1,5)
```

Then db query:

```
SELECT question FROM your_table WHERE ques_id = num;
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT question FROM your_table LIMIT num-1, 1;
```

num would be a random number between 1 and 5,  replace `num` in the query and it only returns 1 row. Be aware it is starting from index 0, therefore the first argument should be `num-1` other than `num`, second argument is always 1 because you only want to get one row per query.

Answer (score 1):

If all the Ids are in order, get the max one and use the random library to get a random number from 1 to the max id in database.

```
from random import randint

random_id = randint(1,my_max_id)
```

then use `random_id` to get the item from the database.

If you have not setup your python mysql connection, you can refer this 
[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it at the database level (in MySQL) and thus you would gain an extra speed (by doing the calculations in a lower level of software).

In MySQL, you could get all the questions that you are going to show in a random way.

```
SELECT qus_id, question FROM your_table ORDER BY RAND();
```

And then, in python show them by sequentially obtaining the records previously out of order in MySQL.

```
for question in rows:
    show_question(question)
```

Any "Random" operation is costly to process, so the lower the software level at which it is calculated, the more optimal your program will be.