# Python Sqlite: How would you randomly select a value-specific row?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to be able to randomly select rows that have a certain value. For example, I have a student table in sqlite that stores different characteristics (i.e Gender). I want to randomly pick a student that is male using python. I have looked at other questions (e.g [Select a random row from the table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149394/select-a-random-row-from-the-table-using-python)) but isn't relevant to value specific rows. How would I do this?

Comment: If you don't care about performance, you can do it all in SQL `SELECT * FROM students WHERE gender = 'male' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` (unsure if SQLite has `ORDER BY RAND()` but I believe it does)

Comment: Its for my school project which has required me to use Python to manipulate a database.

Comment: Fine. `conn = sqlite3.connect(); conn.query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE gender = 'male' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1')`. But you really should be try this out yourself before asking SO. You won't learn anything by asking someone else how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No python specific syntax is needed: sqlite has a [`random()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) function:

```sql
select
  *
from users

where gender == 'M'

order by random()

limit 1
```

For performance see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591688/788700