# How to store MQTT Mosquitto publish events into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mqtt, mosquitto

I've connected a device that communicates to my mosquitto MQTT server (RPi) and is sending out publications to a specified topic. What I want to do now is to store the messages published on that topic on the MQTT server into a MySQL database. I know how MySQL works, but I don't know how to listen for these incoming publications. I'm looking for a light-weight solution that runs in the background. Any pointers or ideas on libraries to use are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar in the last days:

- live-collecting weatherstation-data with pywws
- publishing with pywws.service.mqtt to mqtt-Broker
- **python-script** on NAS collecting the data and writing to MariaDB

```py
#!/usr/bin/python -u

import mysql.connector as mariadb
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='USER', password='PW', database='MYDB')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

# MQTT Settings 
MQTT_Broker = "192.XXX.XXX.XXX"
MQTT_Port = 8883
Keep_Alive_Interval = 60
MQTT_Topic = "/weather/pywws/#"

# Subscribe
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  mqttc.subscribe(MQTT_Topic, 0)

def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
  # Prepare Data, separate columns and values
  msg_clear = msg.payload.translate(None, '{}""').split(", ")
  msg_dict =    {}
  for i in range(0, len(msg_clear)):
    msg_dict[msg_clear[i].split(": ")[0]] = msg_clear[i].split(": ")[1]

  # Prepare dynamic sql-statement
  placeholders = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(msg_dict))
  columns = ', '.join(msg_dict.keys())
  sql = "INSERT INTO pws ( %s ) VALUES ( %s )" % (columns, placeholders)

  # Save Data into DB Table
  try:
      cursor.execute(sql, msg_dict.values())
  except mariadb.Error as error:
      print("Error: {}".format(error))
  mariadb_connection.commit()

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):
  pass

mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

# Connect
mqttc.tls_set(ca_certs="ca.crt", tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
mqttc.connect(MQTT_Broker, int(MQTT_Port), int(Keep_Alive_Interval))

# Continue the network loop & close db-connection
mqttc.loop_forever()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Python the [Paho MQTT library](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/) is simple, light on resources, and interfaces well with Mosquitto. To use it simply subscribe to the topic and set up a callback to pass the payload to MySQL using peewee as shown in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622308/7746400) Run the script in the background and call it good!