# How can I store informations in MySQL using Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to store simple informations, like numbers in a mysql table using python.
I linked my MySQL local server to PyCharm and I just don't know how to write the code in order to store the information in a table.
I was thinking to use some simple "if's" and the printed result to be imediately stored in a certain table.

How can I do this?

Thanks!
For starters, if I could store only the price, it would be great.
Piece of my code:

```
    running = True

while running:
    try:
        buget = int(input("Money: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter your buget using only numbers!")
        continue
    else:
        print("Continue to the next step.")
        break

class Cars:
    def __init__(self,model,consumption,price,transmision):
        self.model = model
        self.consumption = consumption
        self.price = price
        self.transmision = transmision
        self.combination = model + " " + price

car_1 = Cars("BMW", "7%", "20000", ["Manual"])
car_2 = Cars("Audi", "8%", "30000 euro", ["Automated"])
car = (car_1, car_2)

for masini in car:
    guess = str(input("What car would you like? ").capitalize())
    if guess == "Bmw" and buget >= 20000:
        print("-----------------")
        print(car_1.model)
        print(car_1.consumption)
        print(car_1.price)
        print(",".join(car_1.transmision))
        print(car_1.combination)
    elif guess == "Audi" and buget >= 30000:
        print("-----------------")
        print(car_2.model)
        print(car_2.consumption)
        print(car_2.price)
        print(",".join(car_2.transmision))
        print(car_2.combination)
    elif guess == "Bmw" and buget < 20000:
        print("You can't afford this car.")
    elif guess == "Audi" and buget < 30000:
        print("You can't afford this car.")
    elif guess is not "Audi" and buget < 30000:
        print("This car doesn't exist!")
    elif guess is not "Bmw" and buget < 20000:
        print("This car doesn't exist.")
    else:
        print("This car is unavailable!")
    break
```

Comment: SO is not a replacement for the numerous online tutorials on relational databases and python db-api.

Comment: Have a look at pymysql library and do it with for loops similar to what you have with the print statements or put it into a pandas dataframe and run `pandas.to_sql` on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a driver which handles your connection. One which is wildly used is called: `MySQLdb` you can install it with pip or manually:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

After you have the module you can connect to the db this way:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )
```

Make sure that you have imported the module at the top of your script with `import MySQLdb`. After this, you can start using the database. See a really good tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm).

Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) as well.