# Python connect to MySQL error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I keep getting this error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when I want to connect Python with MySQL?

The exact error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cone.py", line 4, in 
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(f)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 57, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here's my code:

```
import mysql.connector

f="localhost","username","password","db"
conn = mysql.connector.connect(f)

c= conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM test")

rows=c.fetchall()

for eachRow in rows:
    print (eachRow)
```

Comment: shouldn't that be :`SELECT * FROM test`

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Telling you which line caused the problem?

Comment: What examples are you following to get the `connector.connect(f)` syntax?

Comment: yeah you're right thx for the hint now i changed it from SELECT = FROM test to SELECT* FROM test but I still have the same Issue with the Arguments

Comment: @khelwood yeah it says line 4

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the stack trace.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well I just tried it with MySQLdb.connect but it said that ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: Than install it,are you on Python3?

Comment: @MishaVacic yeah im on Python3 but wehn I wanna install it with pip install MySQL-Python  it just says that the Requirement is already up to date

Comment: Instead of answering these comments, please edit your question with the exact error you're receiving, in full, for the exact code you're trying.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34503728/2308683 (and others)

Comment: @pvg this is the exact code

Comment: @cricket_007 thx for the answer will try it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="host", user="username",   password ="pwd", database="db")
```

Comment: yeah tried it but then it said TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given but thx for the answer

Comment: @Flo if you didnt provide arguments it will say like this.. so give assignment like user etc

Comment: @Flo Did you give keyword arguments? You have to. Read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

Answer (score 1):

in python3.4 try the same using pymysql,

to install `pip3 install PyMySQL`

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect("localhost","dev","pwd","db_name")
cur = conn.cursor()
```

should connect like this in `mysql.connector.connect`

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="uname", password="mypwd", database="emp_db")
```

For example,

```
>>> conn = mysql.connector.connect(f)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 98, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>> conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="uname", password="pwd", database="reposter$tutorial_database")
>>>
```

here is the [Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)

Comment: thx for the answer but i already tried it with conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="uname", password="mypwd", database="emp_db") than it said:TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

Comment: what it says? >>> conn = mysql.connector.connect("localhost","dev","pwd","my_db")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 98, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
>>>

Comment: if you gave like this it will through an error.. otherwise it should work..

Comment: You're missing that the other error correctly says 5 *positional* arguments were given

Comment: @cricket_007 you OP missing or me?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cone.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = mysql.connector.connect("localhost","usernamer","pw","database")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 57, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

Comment: @Mohi try reproducing in Python34

Answer (score 1):

If you have managed to fix MySQLdb then you can connect like this

```
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'flo',passwd = '********',db = 'yourdb')
cur = mydb.cursor()
command = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM yourtable')
results = cur.fetchall()

print (results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import mysql connector
import mysql.connector

#declare your database variables
DBHOST = 'localhost'
DBNAME = 'database_name'
DBUSER = 'root'
DBPASS = ''

#establish the connection
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=DBHOST, database=DBNAME, user=DBUSER, passwd=DBPASS)
```