# AWS RDS: Connecting with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance and an Amazon RDS DB(MySQL) instance that both run in Amazon Virtual Private Cloud. I was looking to connect these instances using Python, but I have never connected an RDS before.

Does anyone have experience doing this that could assist?

Comment: If you ask a specific question, you might get specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to RDS is no different than connecting to a standard MySQL instance. This answer should help - [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Also, routing and networking might be a limiting factor to establishing a connecting. You will need a public IP on the instance or be able to route to the private IP space.