# Generating a 1 GB file in python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a question about the approach of my problem and if I am understanding or if I'm not if anyone can help me understand it better:

For my course in python I was tasked with having  to make a 1 GB file with six columns where

- first column id needs to be auto increment
- second column needs to to be a random integer 1-100
- third and fourth column are random 6 letter strings
- fifth and six columns are a combination of letters and numbers combined.

The output file should have a header row I can use a comma as a delimiter.

My thought process was to use aws use their Linux AMI then download mysql server on to it and create table of 6 columns and then read data into the .csv This is where I get lost am I suppose to use a mysqlconnector to link the table I create to python.

Comment: You either misunderstood your assignment or failed to correctly explain it. This should be a relatively straightforward task with the `csv` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the task you are asekd to do doesnot have anything to do with a mysql database and can be solved much more straightforward.
I would suggest to open a file and write the necessary number of lines.
So you start with writing a header line and then write the next (1GB)/(bites per line) lines with the necessary entries in each columns and close the file.

For how to connect to the database: [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: That's a good option I might do that! I appreciate your feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you do not understand this task, then adding MySQL to it would give more complexity.
This is a straightforward excersise, where you need to:

- define a method that writes a line to csv file
- compute how much each line will take memory (according to the description, each line will take same length), with that you can compute how many lines your csv file needs
- define methods to generate random fixed-size string, number 1-100, etc

Then you simply need to run everything in one loop (incremented value can be taken from this loop).

Helpful links:

- [writing to csv file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
- [generate number](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: Awesome thank you for the break down I appreciate it! Very Helpful