# MySQLdb is hard to locate

Tags: python, mysql

I use this tutorial text as an example, there are others:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
```

If it produces the following result, then it means MySQLdb module is not installed −

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
      import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

To install MySQLdb module, use the following command −

For Ubuntu, use the following command -

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

---

I have gone trough these steps, more or less as described above.
Problem is that the subdirectory "python" does not exist under /usr/bin/
in my file system. I run Linux Mint 18.3. Python 2.7 seems to be the native version installed in Mint (used for several purposes), but I have also installed Python 3.6.4 and wish to use this for development purposes.
Does anyone know in which directory I could expect to find MySQLdb?
Since #!/usr/bin/python is non existent I wonder - has MySQLdb been properly installed? If it has, I have not after several efforts succeded in locating it.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried it again, and was notified:
python-mysqldb is already the newest version (1.3.7-1build2).

Comment: Yes I have. I tried it again now,:
python-mysqldb is already the newest version (1.3.7-1build2).
Good to know that it is instralled, but there is no /usr/bin/python directory to import MySGLdb from. 
using
sudo ls -aRl | grep MySQLdb
gave hits, and 1 that makes sense:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb
and there is  a script (among others) called connections.py.
BUT:
#!/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb
 import MySQLdb as mdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
i.e. no response in my simple test program. So I am grateful for further  suggestions.