# Access to a MySQL database via Jupyter Notebook w/ Python3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I needed access a MySQL database via Jupyter Notebook, on which I run Python 3.6 (Anaconda install). It's a linear workflow, extracting data from the DB and manipulating it in Python/Pandas. No need for an ORM, a simple connector should do. However, the widely [referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python) MySQLdb package doesn't work with Python 3.x.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60896206/4999991). Only change `pip3` package manager with `conda`. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The recommended installation modality for Jupyter on Ubuntu is Anaconda, so the appropriate package manager is conda. Installation via pip/pip3 or apt won't be accessible to the Notebook. conda makes it simple to get at least two good connectors:

1. **pymysql** works well and is easy to install:

`sudo conda install pymysql`

2. The **'official' connector**:

`sudo conda install mysql-connector-python`

I tried pymysql first and it was fine but then switched to the second option due to the availability of extensive [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html).

If your objective is to import the data into a Pandas dataframe then use of the built-in `pd.sql_read_table` or `pd.sql_read_query` is convenient, as it labels the columns etc. It still requires installation of a connector, as discussed above.

An example with MySQL-connector-python, where you need to enter the database DETAILS:

`import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://USER:PASSWORD@HOST/DB_NAME')
example_df = pd.read_sql_table("YOUR_TABLE_NAME", engine)`