# Connecting MySQLServer from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I wrote this piece of code to connect the MySQLServer from Jupyter notebook:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(‘mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3306/dbname′)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-12-c958f7670e02>", line 6
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(‘mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3306/events′)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

[image]

`pip list` command also lists `PyMySQL (0.9.2)`.

Comment: `mysql` isn't defined, and `‘` is not a valid apostrophe

Comment: I used this guideline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359627/access-to-a-mysql-database-via-jupyter-notebook-w-python3.

Still it shows : ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'

Comment: Did you pip install it?

Comment: cannot remember. Installed 1 year back. import pymysql perfectly works with gedit editor.

Comment: Well that would be the first thing to check...

Comment: @roganjosh : Please see the image I added to my main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180687/discussion-between-debbie-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score -1):

Replace ‘ character to ' .

Here is new code:

import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:password@localhost:3306/dbname')

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'mysql'

Comment: For Python 3.6.5 install modules:

pip install pymysql
pip install mysql-connector-python